# Express session and redirect inside socket.io event

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm new to NodeJs and i'm trying to find a way to define an express session variable on socket.io events, but dunno if it's possible.

Would like to do these two action, but inside a socket.io event

```
req.session.user = data.login;
res.redirect('/');
```

My purpose is : When the user logs successfully, to redirect him and add a session variable named 'user' in order to reach the main page.

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.render('accueil.html',{});
    } else {
        res.redirect('/connection');
    }
});
```

Here is my client side code :

```
var express = require('express');
var swig = require('swig');
var ent = require('ent');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Environnement
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view cache', false);
swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });
app.use(session({
    secret: 'poussixthetruefighteroftheparadise',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

//MongoDB
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/maBase');
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:  String,
    mail: String,
    password: String,
    friends: [],
    friends_demand: [],
    default_sound: String
});
var user = db.model('user', userSchema);



// Page Principale
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.render('accueil.html',{});
    } else {
        res.redirect('/connection');
    }
});


// Page connection
app.get('/connection', function(req,res){
    res.render('index.html',{});
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('sub_data', function(data){
        if (data.pass1.length > 6) {
            if (data.pass1 == data.pass2) {
                user.find({$or: [{username: data.username}, {mail: data.email}]}).limit(1).exec(function(err,users){
                    if (!users.length) {
                                var values = new user({
                                    username: ent.encode(data.username),
                                    mail: ent.encode(data.email),
                                    password: ent.encode(data.pass1)
                                });
                                values.save(function(){socket.emit('sub_instruction',{message: "k"});});
                    } else {
                        if (users[0].mail == data.email) {
                            socket.emit('sub_instruction', {message: "Cette adresse mail a déja été utilisé."});
                        } else { socket.emit('sub_instruction', {message: "Ce nom d'utilisateur existe déja."});}
                    }
                });
            } else {socket.emit('sub_instruction', {message: "Les mots de passes doivent être identiques."});}
        } else {socket.emit('sub_instruction', {message: "Le mot de passe doit contenir au minimum 7 caractères."});} 
    });

    socket.on('con_data', function(data){
        user.find({$or: [{username: data.login, password: data.pass},{mail: data.login, password: data.pass}]}).limit(1).exec(function(err, users){
            if (!users.length) {
                socket.emit('con_instruction', {message: "Login ou mot de passe incorrect."});
            }
            else {
                req.session.user = data.login;
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [passport](http://passportjs.org) and [passport.socketio](http://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio).

With passport you can have a `req.user` which is added and managed through the use of sessions all automatically by passport.js

And with passport.socketio you can have the same `req.user` (as `socket.request.user`) in your sockets handler.

Comment: and so if i change socket.request.user, does it change req.session.user too?

Comment: @user3595813 There will be a `req.user` and `socket.request.user` (no `req.session.user`) and yes, they both will be the same mongo document instance (if you're using mongo) that you retrieve through passport deserialization. So you can do `.save()` on either.